# Class mailer does not exist when using ANY artisan command

Tags: laravel, virtualbox

Im getting this error in my laravel project:
`Class mailer does not exist` inside of my vagrant machine whenever I try to run ANY `php artisan` command. My project has loaded into the vm no problem. I have seen multiple solution involving using the `cache:clear` command as well as actually including the class `Mailer` in `App.php`, however this class is already imported and well..any artisan command I use returns this error?

Comment: Have you tried `composer update`?

Comment: Yep multiple times, starting to lose my mind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a couple things to check:

1. Check for namespacing on the mailer class. Is your code looking for mailer or App\mailer, etc.?
2. Check for proper casing (mailer versus Mailer for example). This is exceptionally common if you're developing on a Windows machine then switching to a Linux VM.
3. If you've tried composer update, try composer dump-autoload

Do you have a sample of the code where you are trying to access mailer?

Comment: Good call on #2. If OP copy/pasted their error verbatim, that lowercasing is a key clue.

Answer (score 0):

Running the correct php artisan commands outside of my vm as well as running `composer install/update` will usually fix these issues.